# Why operator = doesn't get inherited from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have following template code:

```
class ClassName{};

template <class T>
class TemplatePtr
{
public:
    void operator=(T* p)
    {

    }
};

class TemplatePtr_ClassName: public TemplateePtr<ClassName>
{
public:
    ~TempaltePtr_ClassName();
};


void Test()
{
    TemplatePtr_ClassName data;
    data = new ClassName;
}
```

but compile fails with error message (VS2008):

> > error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type     >>'ClassName *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Why it won't work as I have defined an operator in the template base class?

Comment: I am scared to ask why you want that overload.

Comment: @Roger Pate See that destructor? I want to do some clearup work myself, which is not provided in the base template class, and which might be different for different calsses

Comment: @lz_prgmr: I understand the inheritance (though you should look at traits classes), but not the overload in TemplatePtr.

Comment: @Roger Pate In fact, This is extract from a large template class to show the problem clearer. That template class is designed to use like a SmartPtr, but I found I need to do some clearup work, so I inherit it.

Comment: @Roger Pate traits classes is a good idea, but I may don't have permission to change implementation of TemplatePtr (or don't want to introduce risk by changing a very low-level, widely-used class when approaching release)

Comment: Fair enough; I don't know nearly as much about your project as you do. :) But I do know this is the type of situation where they are particularly useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

operator = is always hidden by the derived class implementation unless explicit using declaration is provided. This is true for both class templates and ordinary classes.

BTW, your declaration of operator= is very nonstandard. It is usually declared so for a class 'A'.

```
A& operator=(A const &);
```

Here is something that may be what you are looking for (and compiles)

```
template <class T> 
class TemplatePtr 
{ 
public: 
    TemplatePtr& operator=(TemplatePtr const &) 
    {return *this;} 
}; 

template<class T>
class TemplatePtr_ClassName: public TemplatePtr<T> 
{ 
public:
   ~TemplatePtr_ClassName(){};
   TemplatePtr_ClassName& operator=(TemplatePtr_ClassName const &that){
      TemplatePtr<T>::operator=(that);        // invoke base class assignment operator
      return *this;
   }
}; 


int main() 
{ 
    TemplatePtr_ClassName<int> data; 
    data = *new TemplatePtr_ClassName<int>; 
    // delete stuff
}
```

Comment: The code for the `using` declaration mentioned in the answer would be: `using TemplatePtr<T>::operator=;` inside the class curly braces in the `TemplatePtr_ClassName` class. The shortcoming of the `using` declaration is that it will also bring `TemplatePtr<T>::operator=( TemplatePtr<T> const & )` (implicitly defined assignment operator in the base type) into scope, so not only you will be able to assign a `T*` to the derived class, but also a `TemplatePtr<T> const &`.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I showed a working code on using the base class assignment operator from derived class (and not using the 'using' directive)

Comment: @Chubsdad My intention is to be able to assign from a T* and I want to write my own destructor to do cleanup specifically. So your way may not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: @lz_prgmr: You can overload operator= for T* as well. TemplatePtr_ClassName& operator=(T const *that);

Comment: @Chubsdad your class design inspires me to provide a common used template class to cleanup stuff in its destructor for certain types, without changing its base template class. I think this is the best choice for my current situation.

Answer (score 14):

It gets inherited. However, the compiler-generated assignment operator for `TempaltePtr_ClassName` hides the inherited operator. You can make it visible by adding

```
using TempaltePtr<ClassName>::operator=;
```

to your derived class.

Comment: This has the shortcoming of also bringing `TemplatePtr<T>::operator=( Template<T> const & )` into scope, which may not be wanted.

Comment: Does that mean all compiler generatable functions will hide base class's implementations: constructor, destructor, copy constructor, operator =, operator &?

Comment: @Iz_prgmr Yes. This is most visible in the case of non-default constructors. E.g., if you had a TempaltePtr::TempaltePtr(T* p) constructor, you would have to add a `TempaltePtr_ClassName::TempaltePtr_ClassName(ClassName* p) : TempaltePtr<Classname>(p) {}` to your class.

Comment: @lz_prgmr, well, constructors and destructors don't have names and therefore cannot be hidden. The only other special member function is operator=. Operator & is not a special member function -- compiler does not generate one.

Comment: @Sjoerd, that's not due to hiding. You can't use `using` to unhide "inherited constructors".

Comment: @avakar you are right, operator & is different from operator =, if I implement operator &　in a base class, it is derived class will inherit it without hiding. Seems opearotr = is the only case that would be hidden by derived classes.

Comment: @lz_prgmr, yes, default constructor, copy constructor, destructor and copy-assignment operator are the only *special member functions* (that's the term they are referred to by the standard).

Comment: @avakar I accept Chubsdad's answer as I think it would solve my current problem. However, you really provide much useful information, so I vote up your answer and comments to give you the credit your deserve.