# Assignment operator inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){
        std::cout << "Constructor base" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Base(){
        std::cout << "Destructor base" << std::endl;
    }
    Base& operator=(const Base& a){
        std::cout << "Assignment base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:

};

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Derived p;
    Derived p2;
    p2 = p;
    return 0;
}
```

The output after compilation by g++ 4.6:

```
Constructor base
Constructor base
Assignment base
Destructor base
Destructor base
```

Why assignment operator of base class is called altough it is said that assignment operator is not inherited?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with inheritance of operator= in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have a default

```
Derived& operator=(const Base& a);
```

in your `Derived` class.

A default assignment operator, however, is created:

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& a);
```

and this calls the assignment operator from `Base`. So it's not a matter of inheriting the assignment operator, but calling it via the default generated operator in your derived class.

Comment: operator= is inherit from based class as I quote from 98 c++ standard "Operator functions are inherited in the same manner as other base class functions." It has just been hidden by implicitly created operator= for Derived class.

Comment: "It has just been hidden by implicitly created operator= for Derived class". Just like if base class has void func(int) and derived class has void func(double), base class function void func(int) is hidden. On similar lines base class operator= is hidden by derived class operator=.

Comment: ...and to be clear, since the base `operator=` has only been hidden, it can be unhidden in the derived class with `using Base::operator=;` and boom: there it is, inherited. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122214/why-operator-doesnt-get-inherited-from-a-template-class

Comment: @Luchian: if it is not inherited make it private in base class and see the result

Answer (score 49):

Actually, what is called is the implicitly defined `operator =` for `Derived`. The definition provided by the compiler in turn calls `operator =` for the `Base` and you see the corresponding output. The same is with the  constructor and destructor. When you leave it to the compiler to define `operator =`, it defines it as follows:

```
Derived& operator = (const Derived& rhs)
{
    Base1::operator =(rhs);
    ...
    Basen::operator =(rhs);
    member1 = rhs.member1;
    ...
    membern = rhs.membern; 
}
```

where `Base1,...,Basen` are the bases of the class (in order of specifying them in the inheritance list) and `member1, ..., membern` are the members of Derived (not counting the members that were inherited) in the order you declared them in the class definition.

Comment: It would be good to add a `return` statement to that definition, probably it just does `return *this`? Which might be different to the behavior of `Base1` if `Base1`'s operator does not return a reference to itself (which is *normally* the case though).

Answer (score 42):

You can also use "using":

```
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    using Base::operator=;
};
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

I read this post several time before someone helped me with this.

Comment: Finally, someone said it. +1. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122214/why-operator-doesnt-get-inherited-from-a-template-class

Comment: What happens if you declare additional variables in the Derived class, but use this technique? Will it properly assign the new variables from Derived?

Answer (score 11):

Standard says (12.8):

> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member
>   function with exactly one parameter. Because a copy assignment
>   operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared
>   by the user (12.8), a base class assignment operator is always hidden
>   by the copy assignment operator of the derived class.

and then assignment operator of derived call your base

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union
>   class X performs memberwise copy-/move assignment of its subobjects.
>   The direct base classes of X are assigned first, in the order of their
>   declaration in the base-specifier-list, and then the immediate
>   non-static data members of X are assigned, in the order in which they
>   were declared in the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

That is because the default assignment operator created calls it's base assignment operator, i.e. it isn't inherited but still called as part of the default assignment operator.

Comment: The assignment operator **is** inherited from the base. It's just hidden by the compiler-generated one in the derived class. Using `using Base::operator=;` would prove this by unhiding the base implementation and making it available via the derived class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122214/why-operator-doesnt-get-inherited-from-a-template-class

Answer (score -1):

Assignment operator is indeed not inherited. Inheriting that operator would enable you to assign a `Base` to a `Derived`, however `Base b; p = a;` will (rightfully) fail to compile.

What happens is that the compiler generates an `operator=`, since you haven't defined a custom one for `Derived`. The autogenerated `operator=` will call the assignment operators of all all base classes and all members. In that aspect it is much the same as constructors/destructors, which also call the respective function on all Bases/members.

Comment: The assignment operator **is** inherited from the base. It's just hidden by the compiler-generated one in the derived class. Using `using Base::operator=;` would prove this by unhiding the base implementation and making it available via the derived class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122214/why-operator-doesnt-get-inherited-from-a-template-class