# Why does an overloaded assignment operator not get inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Why does this code:

```
class X {
public:
    X& operator=(int p) {
        return *this;
    }
    X& operator+(int p) {
        return *this;
    }
};

class Y : public X { };

int main() {
    X x;
    Y y;
    x + 2;
    y + 3;
    x = 2;
    y = 3;
}
```

Give the error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:14:9: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘y = 3’
prog.cpp:14:9: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:8:7: note: Y& Y::operator=(const Y&)
prog.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Y&’
prog.cpp:8:7: note: Y& Y::operator=(Y&&)
prog.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Y&&’
```

Why is the `+` operator inherited, but the `=` operator not?

Comment: The answer to your question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009865/operator-and-functions-that-are-not-inherited-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class `Y` contains implicitly-declared assignment operators, which hide the operator declared in the base class. In general, declaring a function in a derived class hides any function with the same name declared in a base class.

If you want to make both available in `Y`, use a using-declaration:

```
class Y : public X {
public:
    using X::operator=;
};
```

Comment: What if class `Y` needs to "extend" the operator `=`, i.e. do more things than `return *this` in parent class?

Comment: Then you override it yourself as you did initially and don't use inheritance. I have personally found that using virtual operator overloads are not always the best thing

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the methods that the compiler automatically generates if they are not declared. Assignment is amongst them.

Comment: Why does automatic generation delete my definition, when they have different signatures?

Comment: @Eric: It doesn't delete it, it hides it.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Same question then: why does it hide it, when the signatures don't conflict?

Comment: @Eric: Because any function declared in a derived class hides any function with the same *name* (not signature) declared in a base class.

Comment: @Eric hiding does not require signatures to match. It works at the level of *names*.