# Is it necessary to overload the assignment operator and the copy constructor for a class A which has a data member of another class B?

Tags: c++

I have a class `List`, which has as a member of pointer of type `Vector` (my own class). For this class I have overloaded the assignment operator and redefined the copy-constructor.

The problem is that I am not sure if a have to do the same thing for a new class, which has a member of type `List` (not dynamically allocated).

```
class List {
    Vector *l;
    int len;
    // assignment operator and copy-constructor defined here
}

class Graf_Neorientat : public Graf {
    List L;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Perhaps [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009865/operator-and-functions-that-are-not-inherited-in-c) is of help.

Comment: Kind of explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). If you have not given it a read you should You should also see the rule of zero section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @Ron This is not about inheritance, though. `L` is just a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member variable `L` in your `Graf_Neorientat` class can be assigned and copied just the same way as if it was a normal variable in your program. So you don't need to do write again that code in `Graf_Neorientat` to be able to copy `L` when `Graf_Neorientat` is copied.

Now, probably what you wanted to ask instead is if you need to do something "extra" in `Graf_Neorientat` to make it also copyable (and copy `L` when doing so).

Assuming `Graf` is copyable (or ignoring `Graf`), the answer is no. If your `List` class is copyable, then your `Graf_Neorientat` will be copyable. The compiler will define implicitly the assignment operator and copy constructor for you, which will call in turn the `List` ones to copy the `L` member appropriately.

Of course, you can disable copyability yourself in `Graf_Neorientat` if you want in several ways, and you can also define a different assignment operator and copy constructor if you wish to do something else (rare). But, as given in your example, `Graf_Neorientat` will do what you expect.